# Spring Expression Language check if a string is contained in a List of Strings

Tags: java, spring, spring-el

I have the following SPEL test code:

```
public void test(){
    ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

    String input = "ADITYA";
    List<String> coreTeam = Arrays.asList("ASHISH","ADITYA","SUMANT","SHASHIKANT","HATIM");

    System.out.println(coreTeam.toString());

    StandardEvaluationContext coreTeamContext = new StandardEvaluationContext(coreTeam);
    coreTeamContext.setVariable("CORE_TEAM",coreTeam);
    coreTeamContext.setVariable("CHEK_TEAM",input);

    Expression exp40 = parser.parseExpression("#CORE_TEAM.contains(#CHECK_TEAM)");
    Boolean s = exp40.getValue(coreTeamContext,Boolean.class);
```

}

The output of which is always false.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's typo error, you typed CHECK_TEAM iso "CHEK_TEAM". The below code will give you true.
ExpressionParser parser = new SpelExpressionParser();

```
 String input = "ADITYA";
    List<String> coreTeam = Arrays.asList("ASHISH","ADITYA","SUMANT","SHASHIKANT","HATIM");

    System.out.println(coreTeam.toString());

    StandardEvaluationContext coreTeamContext = new StandardEvaluationContext(coreTeam);
    coreTeamContext.setVariable("CORE_TEAM",coreTeam);
    coreTeamContext.setVariable("CHEK_TEAM",input);

    Expression exp40 = parser.parseExpression("#CORE_TEAM.contains(#CHEK_TEAM)");
    Boolean s = exp40.getValue(coreTeamContext,Boolean.class);
```